# About the injectivity and surjectivity of the map $T = (\lambda I - K)|_{\mathfrak{R}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I'm reading a question in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220059/fredholm-alternative-for-compact-operators-why-isnt-it-so-simple) thread

> Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a Banach space, and $K\in \mathcal{K}(\mathfrak{X})$ be a compact operator. Then given $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, we can show that
>
> - $\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)$ is *finite dimensional*
> - $\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$ is *closed*
>
> Now, if $\mathfrak{M}\subseteq\mathfrak{X}$ is a finite-dimensional subspace, then $\mathfrak{M}$ is complemented in $\mathfrak{X}$, so there exists a closed subspace $\mathfrak{N}\subseteq\mathfrak{X}$ such that $\mathfrak{X} = \mathfrak{M}\oplus\mathfrak{N}$. Let $\mathfrak{R}$ be $\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)$'s complement in $\mathfrak{X}$, and define
> $$
> T : \mathfrak{R}\to \mathfrak{X},\qquad y\mapsto(\lambda I - K)y
> $$
> or in other words $T = (\lambda I - K)|_{\mathfrak{R}}$. It's easy to see that $T$ is injective, and surjective onto it's range, which is closed. Thus $T$ induces an isomorphism $\mathfrak{R}\cong\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$, and so
> $$
> \mathfrak{X}\cong\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K).
> $$

I think the reasoning

> ... $T$ is injective, and surjective onto it's range, ... so
> $$
> \mathfrak{X}\cong\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K).
> $$

is not true. This is because $T$ is not necessarily injective. So the decomposition $\mathfrak{X}\cong\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$ is not true.

Could you confirm if my above understanding is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $T$ is injective.

By definition $\mathfrak R$ is a complement of $\ker T$. If $x\in\mathfrak R$ and $Tx=0$, then $$x\in\mathfrak R\cap\ker T=\{0\}.$$

Comment: Ah $T$ is the restriction of $\lambda I-K$ to $\mathfrak{R}$. Could you confirm if $\mathfrak{X}\cong\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$ is true?

Comment: Yes, the argument you wrote is very clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was confused because I misread $\mathfrak{X}\cong\operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$ as $\mathfrak{X} = \operatorname{ker}(\lambda I - K)\oplus\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - K)$.

Comment: Oh no, you cannot have that in general. It does happen for instance for selfadjoint compact operators on a Hilbert space.